# LogComponentEnable ("UdpClientApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);

Tags: ns-3

Just like

```
LogComponentEnable ("UdpEchoClientApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
```

for UdpEchoServerHelper,
Can i have

```
LogComponentEnable ("UdpClientApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
```

for UdpServerHelper?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.
The UdpServerHelper uses `UdpServer` and `UdpClient`.
To activate logging for the client use:

> LogComponentEnable ("UdpClient", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);

### Background

The helper class/object and the log enable function do not correlate.
NS-3 logging system is global and modules/components register globally.

Descend into the implementations .cc file you want to get logging messages from. The Macro `NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE()` is called with the actual name there. So for `UdpClient` it's [udp-client.cc](http://code.nsnam.org/ns-3.27/file/a6d4461e1a3d/src/applications/model/udp-client.cc), where it says in line 38

> NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("UdpClient");